# How to use uuid as item id?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

My get request seems to work. I used to have id's like this 1,2,3,4
Now I want to make them as uuid
I've made a table for this

```
CREATE TABLE todo_list(
    todo_id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(255),
);
```

```
router.post("/todo", async (req, res) => {
    try {
       const { description } = req.body;
       const newTodo = await pool.query("INSERT INTO todo_list (description) VALUES($1)"
       , [description]);

        res.json(newTodo.rows[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
});
```

But my post request wont work anymore after I changed ID to uuid.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What did the `id` column definition look before? And where are you generating the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not providing a default value for `todo_id`, and aren't passing it into insert statement. You could either generate a UUID at the application layer, or change the DDL from:

```
CREATE TABLE todo_list(
    todo_id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(255),
);
```

to:

```
CREATE TABLE todo_list(
    todo_id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    description VARCHAR(255),
);
```

in order to have PostgreSQL dynamically generate a UUID.

[related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274291/postgresql-uuid-or-sequence-for-primary-key#answer-33274393)